# Gremlin's "mean" equivalent in Java (Blueprints 2.6)

Tags: java, orientdb, gremlin

I'm using OrientDB 2.1.6 and have the following Gremling example query:

```
g.V("username", "testark").out("IsFriendsWith").height.mean()
```

This works great on the Gremlin shell, but I need to be able to use that from within Java. Using the Java Graph API I could translate most of it to

```
final GremlinPipeline<Long, Vertex> pipe = new GremlinPipeline<>(orientGraph);
pipe.V("username", "testark").out("IsFriendsWith").property("height").????????
```

but not I cannot seem to find the equivalent of the `mean` function. My current workaround involves computing the mean "manually" based on the return value of `property`, but I'd obviously prefer to get that value from the database via Gremlin. Can anyone please point out to me what's the equivalent of `mean`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `mean` function is a method of gremlin-groovy so you won't find it on the Java side:

https://github.com/tinkerpop/gremlin/blob/88de5e5d95bd0b704c5090c43a04a3d42992dfb9/gremlin-groovy/src/main/groovy/com/tinkerpop/gremlin/groovy/loaders/PipeLoader.groovy#L28-L35

You would need to do as you are doing and manually calculate the mean.